# How to avoid unnecessary copying when whether the return type is a Rvalue or an Lvalue is decided at run time?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, reference

Consider the following line

```
const auto x = condition ? getLvalue() : getRvalue();
```

Because `x` is const, I don't need to copy the value returned by `getLvalue`, I would be happy if I could just take a reference to it. Of coure, the following would not compile

```
const auto& x = condition ? getLvalue() : getRvalue(); // Compilation error
```

as it makes no sense to make a reference to an R value.

How do I go around this problem? Is there problem or can I just trust the compiler to understand that the return type of `getLvalue` does not need copying?

Comment: Have you tried `const auto&& x = ...`?

Comment: We call && a universal reference. Maybe a little outdated but worth a read [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: You can use `std::move(getLvalue())`.

Comment: @AlexHodges Are you sure it will help here?  The value category of the conditional expression is fixed anyway, so the universal reference does not help AFAIK ...

Comment: A universal reference will become either a lvalue or rvalue depending on what it's initialized with. Since your reference could be either l or r, it seems fitting to use a universal ref, and then std::forward to whatever needs the ref.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of close, but perhaps a `std::variant<T, std::reference_wrapper<T>>`?

You can't really use a ternary operator to assign because it requires a `std::common_type`, but it works fine for regular `if...else`:

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WyHv5DJyQ5LYA0X4) (requires C++17)

Code:

```
int choice = 0;
std::cin >> choice;
std::variant<int, std::reference_wrapper<int>> opt;
if (choice == 0)
    opt = getRValue();
else
    opt = std::ref(getLValue());
```

stubs for `getRValue()` and `getLValue()`:

```
int& getLValue(){
    static int foo = 42;
    return foo;
}

int getRValue(){
    return 1337;
}
```

And we can visit the variant to print:

```
struct visitor
{
    void operator()(int _val)
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue value: " << _val;
    }
    void operator()(std::reference_wrapper<int> _val)
    {
        std::cout << "reference_wrapper value: " << _val << std::endl;
        _val += 1;
    }
};
```

In the `reference_wrapper` overload, I increment the value so we can be sure that it's still a reference.